# Async loading images

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I am quite new to async coding and processes in python, and I am trying to learn myself the logic behind how these processes work. Currently I am trying to create a class containing async method for loading images, and I was wondering if the following code imposes any race conditions or is correctly implemented. Every new knowledge or advice is deeply appreciated!.

```
import asyncio
import PIL

from pathlib import Path 
from typing import Union, Optional
from PIL import Image 


from utils.customexception import SuffixException

class LoadImage:
    def __init__(self, path: Union[str, Path]) -> None:
        self.path = Path(path)
        self.cache_path = None

        self.supported_image_exstension = [
            '.jpg', 
            '.jpeg', 
            '.png', 
            '.gif'
        ]

    def _batch(self, ratio: dict[str]) -> list[str]:
        pass 

    def _fetch_path(self, subdir: Union[str, Path]) -> None:
        if subdir:
            self.path = self.path + subdir
            if self.path.is_file():
                pass 
            else:
                raise FileNotFoundError(f"The given subdir: '{subdir}' does not exist")

        self.cache_path = [entry for entry in self.path.iterdir() if entry.name != '.DS_Store']
        

    async def _loadimage(self, image_path: Path):
    
        if image_path.suffix in self.supported_image_exstension:
            try:
                return Image.open(image_path)
            except Exception as err:
                print(f"Error loading image at path {image_path} with exception: {err}")
        else:
            raise SuffixException()


    async def load(self, subdir: Optional[Union[Path, str]] = None) -> PIL.Image:
        self._fetch_path(subdir=subdir)
        
        for image_path in self.cache_path:
            yield await self._loadimage(image_path=image_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The major issue with your so-called async method for loading images is that it is not asynchronous at all.

Python async code using asyncio is about cooperative concurrency: this means that one task have to explicitly allow other tasks to run concurrently - and that is done by using expression with `await` - or `async for/with` statements.

Your `async def _loadimage`  function, while being able to be called as a co-routine, contains no such "pauses" where it would delegate control to the asyncio loop: so, any delays in it for loading the images, etc... is blocking. The function is synchronous.

On the other hand loading images is a task that under the hood has some I/O - which could be made asynchronous, and some CPU number crunching to decode the actual image data into flat pixels -you could run it in another thread, and that would enable the main thread, running the async loop to be freed to run other tasks. With the built-in resource of `run_in_executor` of asyncio, you can do that.

So, this has some chance of actually be in async and benefit the caller:

```
    async def _loadimage(self, image_path: Path):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        
        if image_path.suffix in self.supported_image_exstension:
            try:
                img = await loop.run_in_executor(None, Image.open, image_path)
                return img
            except Exception as err:
                print(f"Error loading image at path {image_path} with exception: {err}")
        else:
            raise SuffixException()
```